# Problem accessing a node from a class [GDScript]

Tags: gdscript

I encountered some difficulties while studying Godot.

I'm trying to add a shotgun class (Shotgun.gd). I have a function in the class that creates several RayCasts, a function that checks what they encounter and a function that calls these functions one by one. If I call these functions from the class where they are declared in the _process() function, everything works fine, but if I call these functions in another script, like Player.gd, it finds nothing when checking for RayCasts.

P.S Sorry for the sloppy translation, English is not my native language

Part of the code from the shotgun class (Shotgun.gd)

```
# Gen RayCast-ы
func gen_raycasts(player):
    # Очистка списка
    raycasts.clear()
    var temp
    
    for number in PELLETS_COUNT:
        # Создание RayCast
        temp = RayCast.new()
        
        # Установка настроек
        temp.set_cast_to(Vector3(LENGHT, 0, 0))
        temp.set_enabled(true)
        
        # Добавляет RayCast на сцену
        player.add_child(temp)
        
        # Установка положения
        temp.transform.basis = Basis(Vector3(-0, 0, 0.1), Vector3(-0, 0, 0.1), Vector3(0.1, 0, -0))
        temp.global_translate(Vector3(0, 1.65, 0))
        temp.set_scale(Vector3(0.1, 0.1, -0.1))
        
        # Рандомный разброс дробовика
        randomize()
        temp.rotate_y(deg2rad((-50 + randi() % 100) / 10))
        temp.rotate_x(deg2rad((-50 + randi() % 100) / 10))
        raycasts.append(temp)
        
    #print(raycasts)
        
# Check Rayasts
func chech_raycasts():
    in_raycast.clear()
    for number in PELLETS_COUNT:
        in_raycast.append(raycasts[number].get_collider())
        #print(raycasts[number].is_enabled())
        
    print(in_raycast)
```

[Godot tree picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJXvw.png)

[Call from func _process()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKvDh.png)

[Call from Player.gd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCyWY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll venture to say that it is probably correct they collide with nothing.

Enable "Visible Collision Shapes" in the "Debug" menu, so Godot shows colliders in runtime (including enabled `RayCast`s), and check they are being positioned correctly.

---

I can think of a couple possible problems:

- You are adding the `RayCast` before positioning it. *This is not always a problem, and it is probably not a problem in your case.* However, it might register a collision when added, before moved.
- You are scaling the `RayCast`. *This should not be a problem.* However, there have been bugs related applying a scaling directly on collision shapes… So, I will avoid this, just to be safe.

A suggestion: Add a `Position` node, child of your Shotgun, marking the origin for the `RayCast`s. Then you can copy the global transform of the `Position` to the global transform of the `RayCast`s - and then apply the random rotation - before adding them as children. *This should make it easier to update the position if you need to (e.g. if you changed the shotgun model, you can mode the `Position` node accordingly). It should avoid any typos when writing the coordinates in the code. And it should avoid the pitfalls mentioned above.*

---

I'll remind you you are supposed to check `is_colliding`. *I guess you are not doing it for demonstration purposes.*

I'll also remind you that the `RayCast`s update with the physics frame. So, when calling the `RayCast` from somewhere other than `_physics_process` you are getting what they registered last physics frame (i.e. just before `_physics_process` ran last). You can make Godot update the `RayCast` by calling `force_raycast_update` on them.

---

If you don't need the `RayCast`s often, having them update every physics frame might be overkill. In that case, you might be interested in checking like this: `get_world().direct_space_state.intersect_ray(start, end)`. See [`PhysicsDirectSpaceState`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_physicsdirectspacestate.html). *However, using `RayCast` should work. Using `intersect_ray` is only an optimization.*

---

*Unrelated: if you want to guarantee an uniform probability distribution distribution from the random functions, call `randomize` once at the start, instead of once per iteration. This is probably not noticeable anyway.*

Comment: Many THANKS. Everything was positioned well. Fixed the error by using force_raycast_update(). 

Also took randomize() out of the for loop based on your recommendation.